# Phrase meaning "welcome after", in the sense that someone understood or perceived something later than the majority

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase said to someone when they've understood or perceived something later than the majority or a group of people. For example, a group of students solve a math problem. Then, after a significant amount of time, a student yells the answer. Then students then say the phrase (welcome after).

In Norwegian, there is a phrase; "velkommen etter", said in a mildly derogatory way. It means exactly what I'm after, so I google translated it to see if what it's English equivalent was. When "welcome after" came up, I started to doubt if an English counterpart even exists. I feel like "welcome after" is simply the two words directly translated, and not the phrase's equivalent.

I saw no indication that "welcome after" is actually a phrase when googling it, which is also why I wasn't satisfied with that google translate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of:

- "took you long enough"

  or,
- "Thanks, Captain Obvious!"

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard that phrase.  I have heard sarcastic remarks, such as "Already?" in this situation.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think that will work for my situation. In my case, a group of people have spotted something. Then, someone else runs up to them and tells them about it. With a snarky tone, someone says "welcome after", or the actual phrase that is used in such a situation.

Comment: In that situation, someone might say sarcastically, "No kidding?" or "You don't say!"  A common crass expression for this situation is "No sh**, Sherlock!"

Answer (score 1):

jmrpink mentioned "[It] took you long enough", but there's also "Nice of you to join us" or "Now that you've/you're caught up [with the rest of us]..."